# How to load Webview after sometime in render method React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, header, react-navigation

We are using Webview in our react native project to load URL and showing some web page. It's loading successfully. 
But, There is issue happening in Android.

It is taking some time to loading in iOS and Android,But, In Android, It is hiding the navigationbar and back button too, But, In iOS navigation is displaying always.

But, If I comment webview code, The navigation header and back button showing immediately.

I tried using some flag value, But, It is throwing errors.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     shouldShowWebView: false,
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      shouldShowWebView: true,
    });
  }

     render() {
const injectedJs = `
    window.postMessage(window.location.href);
  `;
    const {
      shouldShowWebView,
    } 

      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.headerView}>
            <View style={styles.navigationActionBar}>
              <View style={styles.backButtonContainer}>
                <IconButton
                  style={styles.backBtn}
                  image={images.back}
                  pressed={handlerGo}
                />
              </View>
            <WebView
              source={{ uri: 'someURL' }}
              style={styles.webView}
              onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()}
              injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
              scalesPageToFit
              onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange}
              ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
              onError={(err) => {
              }}
            />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

In styles class

```
webView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '75%',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
```

My requirement is, It should not hide the navigation bar and back button which is working fine in iOS.

Issue happening only in Android devices.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add your `WebView` style?

Comment: Updated  with style.

Comment: could you change code? `Platform.OS === "ios" ? < SafeAreaView> ... : <View>`

Comment: Then where can I write android code/